# Word Automation Services Error while adding a job

Tags: word-automation

I am getting a weird error in the UAT environment for the word automation services. I am getting the following errors in the logs while adding the jobs for conversion.

- SharePoint Foundation          Topology      8077  Critical  "There are no instances of the Word Automation Services started on any server in this farm. Ensure that at least one
  instance is started on an application server in the farm using the Services on Server page in Central Administration."
- Unknown  Custom 0000 Unexpected "No endpoints were found for the service application. Ensure that the service has been enabled on one or more servers within the SharePoint
  farm.

The error is pointing to service application not configured or online which weird because I have configured it and the status of the service is online as per PS command as shown in the link [here](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-mfkEqi069v0/Tqe761y7wHI/AAAAAAAABkY/IUqAwunytqA/s1024/Word%252520Automation%252520Service%252520Status.png).

I have tried deleting and recreating the service, restarted the server but the error still remains.

Has anyone encountered such kind of an error? Any resolutions?

Thanks,

Soju

Answer (score 4):

Try to open SharePoint Central Administration -> System Settings -> Manage Servers in this farm. There are a list of running services. Check that word automation services is running. If not, go to the Central Administration -> System Settings -> Manage services on server and run this service.

Comment: I have verified the places mentioned and found that the Word Automation Services is missing in both places. I also found that it is missing from list from the PS command Get-SPServiceInstance. Looks like someone has accidentally deleted the Word Automation Services instance on the server. How do I add that back?

Comment: I reinstalled the services using the command. psconfig.exe -cmd services -install. And now the Word Automation Services is available in the list. @Alexander Thanks for your help, it has helped me in resolving the issue.